# Same name for a string and a function

Tags: javascript, function

Right now I'm having a major brain fart. I have this function:

```
function uplodeVirus(){
  console.log('working')
  console.log('uplodeVirus')
  var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[1]
  console.log(form)
  var select = form.children[0]
  console.log(select)
  for (x in select) {
    var lN = select[x].innerHTML // var linkName
    if (lN == "vspam 0.3 [OpenRelay-backdoor.vspam ] (0.003 Gb)"){
      value = select[x].value
      select[x].setAttribute("selected", "selected");
      form.submit()
      break
    }  
  }
}
```

Don't worry its not a real Virus!!! This is a bot for a game called slave hack - for learning purposes

Anyways, when I call the function:

```
var ip = '2.2.2.2'
var uplodeVirus = 'http://www.slavehack.com/index2.php?page=internet&var2=' + ip + '&var3=files&aktie=upload'
var currentUrl = window.location.href
console.log(currentUrl)
console.log(uplodeVirus)
if (currentUrl == uplodeVirus) { //Yes, I made sure that currentUrl = uplodeVirus
  uplodeVirus()
}
```

Nothing happens... but if I take the code out of the function and do this:

```
if (currentUrl == uplodeVirus){ 
  console.log('working')
  console.log('uplodeVirus')
  var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[1]
  console.log(form)
  var select = form.children[0]
  console.log(select)
  for (x in select) {
    var lN = select[x].innerHTML // var linkName
    if (lN == "vspam 0.3 [OpenRelay-backdoor.vspam ] (0.003 Gb)"){
      value = select[x].value
      select[x].setAttribute("selected", "selected");
      form.submit()
      break
    }  
  }
}
```

It works!!! Now, I could go with option B, but I really want to figure out what i did wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd recommend learning to use the JavaScript debugger in your browser to step over the code and find where it fails.

Comment: `uplodeVirus` can't both be a string and a function at the same time. One of the two uses will have to be renamed.

Comment: You're not calling any function. You're assigning a value to a variable.

Comment: Also, you may want to read through: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLonowski And I'll be sure to check up on that

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Thanks I just turned it on and it is helping already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are naming both a URL variable and a function with the same name: `uplodeVirus`

Since the variable is initialized to hold a string before you try to call the function, calling `uplodeVirus()` is the same as calling `("")()`. It doesn't make any sense, because a string is not a function.

Try changing the name of one or the other.